# Show a div tag content on entering a character into a textbox?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am trying to slide down content within a div tag (red rectangle) when a user enters atleast one character in a textbox (green rectangle).

If no character is entered then the div content does not show.

Here is a pic of the aspx (design):

[image]

And this is the JavaScript I am using to try and achieve this:

```
function() {
    $("#SubmitSection").hide();
    inputOne = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>");
    if (inputOne.value != "") {
        $("#SubmitSection").slideDown('slow');
    }
    else {
        $("#SubmitSection").slideUp('slow');
    }
}​
```

All the backend code works just fine but both the textbox and the div section show up when deployed.

Comment: you should subscribe on `onchange` event of a textbox and then perform sliding.

Comment: Im real new to this. Do you mind elaborating on what you mean by "subscribe" an onchange event. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hook up to an event on the textbox. The  `onchange` event only fires after the textbox loses focus, so I suggest the `onkeyup` event.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" [...] onkeyup="updateSubmitSection()" />
```

You will have to name your function so that you can call it:

```
updateSubmitSection = function() {
   $("#SubmitSection").hide();
  inputOne = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>");
  // ...
}
```

In addition to that, you need to call the function during the `onload` event of the page:

```
<body onload='updateSubmitSection()'>
```

The same solution using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    updateSubmitSection();
    $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').change(updateSubmitQuery);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if i got you right :

```
$("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").change(function(){YoursSlidingFunctionhere();})
```

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: FYI: That solution would require jQuery (which is probably already included to make slideUp / slideDown work).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add this to a section of your javascript that is executed on initialization:

```
`$("#SubmitSection").hide();`
```

You could use the body onload attribute:

```
`<body onload="init()">
<script>
function init()
{
$("#SubmitSection").hide();
}
</script> `
```